# How to Get Total time in Two Date time With Different Time zone in c#

Tags: c#

I have to two date time

```
Datetime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-13T00:30");
Datetime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-14T06:05");

d1 Datetime timezone is "8"
d2 Datetime timezone is "-7"
```

how i calculate Total Time Between Two Date time.

i am using this code

```
var calc = (d1 - d2);
var hours = calc.Hours - (d1_timezone - (d2_timezone));
```

but Hours in (-) negative value

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the times into a common timezone and then work out the difference:

```
Datetime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-13T00:30");
Datetime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-14T06:05");

// this is now "2018-03-13T08:30"
Datetime d1Common = d1.AddHours(8);
// this is now "2018-03-13T11:05"
Datetime d2Common = d2.AddHours(-7);

//TimeSpan difference = d1Common - d2Common;
//I'm pretty sure you want the difference this way around.
TimeSpan difference = d2Common - d1Common;
int hoursDifference = difference.TotalHours;
int daysDifference = difference.TotalDays;
//   .....etc.
```

If those are the correct timezones then the difference between d1 and d2 is going to be negative. d1 happened before d2. Even when you allow for the time difference, I think you maybe want `d2Common - d1Common`?

Comment: I like that you wrote _"common"_ instead of forcing the _"UTC"_ even though it would probably be UTC.

Comment: Yeah, OP wasn't clear on this so it could be local time not UTC

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx), which is pretty much `DateTime` with an explicit `Offset` property, so it has a concept of time zones. It exists specifically to handle such cases.

```
var d1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2018-03-13T00:30+8");
var d2 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2018-03-14T06:05-7");
Console.WriteLine((d2 - d1).TotalHours); // -> 44.5833333333333
```